# Trouble with JS object method not changing a boolean property

Tags: javascript, object, methods, conditional-statements

my first question here and I'm only just learning JS, so please be patient.

I'm trying to create an object called rat where you can change whether it's got a tail or not. If the rat has its tail and there is no change (i.e. accident), then it should still have its tail. In the other instances it should not have its tail (so if it's got no tail and has an accident, it still has no tail). The logic I want it to be is:

[logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH88I.png)

Currently the code I've got is this:

```js
function animal(name, age, tail) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.tail = tail;
    this.changeTail = function (tail) {
        tail=true ? this.tail=tail : this.tail=false;
    }
}

var rat = new animal("Arthur", 2, false);
rat.changeTail(true);

document.write(rat.name + '<br />' + rat.age + '<br />has tail: ' + rat.tail);
```

The problem is the result doesn't follow the logic. I would expect it to return `false` when `rat.tail` is set to `false` and `changeTail` is `true` (because a rat can't grow another tail) - but it returns `true` instead.

What am I missing?

Comment: this.changeTail = function (tail)
 {
  tail? this.tail : false;
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error of your code lies on how you are using the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), one of my **favorites**.

An intro to is as follows in pseudocode:

```
variable_getting_value = boolean_expression ? value_returned_if_true : value_returned_if_false;
```

The equivalent of this wordiness:

```
if(boolean_expression)
    return value_returned_if_true;
else
    return value_returned_if_false;
```

In your code, you seem to believe that you can put code inside of the ternary operator, when in reality you have to put in a single value that gets returned. I've edited to code to show what you were actually trying to do.

from

```
tail=true ? this.tail=tail : this.tail=false;
```

to

```
this.tail= this.tail ? tail : this.tail;
```

See the difference? You were on the right path, so good job! Also, I have added the appropriate variable in the code, which is your **this.tail**. Otherwise you are only changing the value of the parameter passed into the function.

```js
/*
If the rat has its tail and there is no change (i.e. accident), then it should still have its tail. In the other instances it should not have its tail (so if it's got no tail and has an accident, it still has no tail). 
*/

function animal(name, age, tail)
{
 this.name = name;
 this.age = age;
 this.tail = tail;
 this.changeTail = function (tail)
 {
  this.tail= this.tail ? tail : this.tail;
 }
}

var rat = new animal("Arthur", 2, false);
rat.changeTail(true);

document.write(rat.name + '<br />' + rat.age + '<br />has tail: ' + rat.tail);
```

Essentially, in the **boolen_expression** of the ternary operator goes the restriction of what to do whether the rat has originally a tail or not. Same wise, if the rat has an accident and in the future has no tail, you can't add one to it. So, if the rat **doesn't have a tail** it will never have it changed, because if **boolean_expression** will always return a **False** and the **value_returned_if_false** will always get returns, which will be **False**. Meanwhile, if the **this.tail** is **True**, like when you create a rat with a tale, then you can have the option of an accident, if the accident occurs, whatever value you passed to **changeTail()** will be the new value for **this.tail**.

Potential pitfalls:

```
var rat = new animal("Arthur", 2, true);
rat.changeTail(false);
```

In this code, the output will be **False** because you are putting the value passed to the function as is. Even worse, if you pass a numeric value, your **this.tail** suddenly becomes a number as well.

```
var rat = new animal("Arthur", 2, true);
rat.changeTail(5);
```

Now **rat.tail** is actually  **5**. Not exactly what was expected right? I added a code snippet addressing this with some inspiration since I am not understanding the concept between `changeTail(true)` `changeTail(false)` and "accident".

```js
/*
    If the rat has its tail and there is no change (i.e. accident), then it should still have its tail. In the other instances it should not have its tail (so if it's got no tail and has an accident, it still has no tail). 
    */

    function animal(name, age, tail)
    {
     this.name = name;
     this.age = age;
     this.tail = tail;
     this.changeTail = function (tail)
     {
      //Check if parameter is not actually boolean
        if (typeof tail != typeof true){
            throw "changeTail only accepts boolean values";
        }
        
        //If you got here, tail is a boolean value, but I don't really understand what should happen if tail is false, so I have taken some liberties with the following
        let accident_occurred = tail && true; 
        //The previous line will return true only if tail is true because of the &&
        //Only makes changes to tail if accident_occurred
        this.tail= this.tail && accident_occurred ? false : this.tail;
        //I put in a solid false value because I am assuming the tail parameter actually means that an accident occurred and you want the tail cut    
     }
    }
    
    animal.prototype.toString = function()
{
    return this.name + '<br />' + this.age + '<br />has tail: ' + this.tail + '<br /><br />';
}

    var rat1 = new animal("Arthur", 2, false);
    rat1.changeTail(true);
    
    var rat2 = new animal("Rosy", 2, true);
    rat2.changeTail(false);
    
    document.write(rat1.name + " change tail true <br/><br/>");
    document.write(rat1);
    document.write(rat2.name + " change tail false <br/><br/>");
    document.write(rat2);
    
    document.write(rat1.name + " change tail false <br/><br/>");
    rat1.changeTail(false);
    document.write(rat1);
    
    document.write(rat2.name + " changet tail true <br/><br/>");
    rat2.changeTail(true);
    document.write(rat2);
```

Comment: That works :) Thank you! I'm still mildly confused by... Edit: No, I've got it. The second 'this tail' is what gets checked and the result is dictated by that. Excellent. Many thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: No problem, that's what Stackoverflow is for. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function animal(name, age, tail)
{
 this.name = name;
 this.age = age;
 this.tail = tail;
 this.changeTail = function (tail)
 {
  this.tail=tail ? false: this.tail;
 }
}

var rat = new animal("Arthur", 2, true);   //initially, tail is intact
var mat = new animal("Matt", 3, false);    //initially, has not tail

console.log(rat.name + ' age: ' + rat.age + ', has tail: ' + rat.tail);
console.log(mat.name + ' age: ' + mat.age + ', has tail: ' + mat.tail);

rat.changeTail(true);                     // accident!
mat.changeTail(true);

console.log(rat.name + ' age: ' + rat.age + ', has tail: ' + rat.tail);
console.log(mat.name + ' age: ' + mat.age + ', has tail: ' + mat.tail);
```

```
function (tail) {
    tail=true ? this.tail=tail : this.tail=false;
}
```

This function does not return any value, and does not affect the instance properties. It only acts upon the paramenter it  was passed to (by value, not reference).

Here is how to fix it:

```
  function (tail) {
         this.tail=tail ? false : this.tail;
    }
```